# Objects have no references in client when serializing them from my WebService

Tags: c#, linq, web-services

I've created a webservice and are using C# and LINQ to create my objects from my database. The tables in the database have relasionships to each other, as have the corresponding objects.

However, in my client that's accesing the webservice, the relationships are gone. This leads me to belive that there is something wrong with the serialization. To get the serialization to work I have edited the LINQ object so that the serialization mode to "unidirectional" and changed the association is set to Access => internal under child property instead of public (otherwise I got a circular reference error).

So, now I can't access an objects references in the client. Does anyone know how to solve it? Is it solvable?

Example, in my webservice I cant write this:

```
Recipe r = new Recipe();
r.RecipeHasCategories();
```

Giving me the relationship between a recipe and a category. This does not work in the client! All I can access there is the attributes specific to that recipe (for example name and description)

Help?

Answer (score 2):

The Entity Framework does not load related objects by default; if you perform operations that require relationships and the entities are still attached to an EF context, then it will perform the loading on demand.

When you serialize objects, they are detached from their context, and this on-demand loading stops working. You only serialize what was already loaded into memory.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx) for how to get all related objects in your original query, via the `.Include()` method.

UPDATE:

Since you are using the older Linq 2 SQL provider, there won't be an `Include` method; you just need to disable deferred object loading completed by setting `DeferredLoadingEnabled` on your context object to `false` before you execute any queries.

Comment: I tried it, but couldn't get it to work. The method .Include() dosn't exist on my LINQ objects.

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? If you're using EF then you should have an `Include` method on each "table" (`ObjectQuery`) in your entity context; you need to use `Include` early because once you get an `IQueryable` back the method isn't there anymore.

Comment: I'm using the LINQ to SQL provided in vs, and can't find the Include()-method. Tried moving things around a lot, but it's not there!